# 0/0 time signature?

Tags: piano, time-signatures

In a piece my brother is playing there's a weird time signature - it looks like a zero over a zero: a 0/0 time signature. It seems that the bars have 5/4 in them (probably not 10/8, but could be as far as I'm concerned). It is stated that the bars are played in tempo rubato.

Any idea what it is?

---

Adding a similar example...

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

0/0 time signature can be used to denote free time, with an irregular number of beats per bar.   A large X as time signature is also sometimes used.

Comment: I have seen "senza misura" to indicate that also.